# Bouncing email between webhost4life & mail.com

Tags: smtp

Looking for a bit of advice diagnosing this... let's assume my personal email address is tony.blair@unforgettable.com. The unforgettable.com domain is associated with mail.com - I use it as a forwarding service to my Google mail account tony.blair@googlemail.com. Last weekend, several friends & colleagues told me that my email was bouncing. It appeared to be a transient thing as by the time I got to a PC, it appeared to be working fine.

However, I'm the author of www.whatpub.org and this system regularly sends out email summaries to users. It's ASP.NET v3/VB.NET based. Email is working fine with everyone else's email addresses except mine. They were just disappearing. Each time www.whatpub.org sends out an email address, it cc's it to another email account at the same time. These cc'd copies **always** got through.

In a flash of inspriation, I remembered that I could configure mail.com to keep a copy of the emails it forwards - so I turned that on and tried a test. This had to be a flash of inspiration as mail.com support haven't singularly failed to reply to any of my posts on the ticket I raised.

Voila - after a while, a non-delivery report arrived in the inbox on mail.com. This is the key bit from the NDR shown below.

The web app is hosted at webhost4life and their SMTP server is 216.10.248.253. There's a link to an AOL page (eh???) that suggests black listing.

[Edited as realised hadn't pasted the right bit]

I don't have enough knowledge of SMTP inner workings to fathom this out or understand those SMTP responses. I also haven't got much faith in mail.com or webhost4life to sort this out :-( That's why I've just registered a personal domain for me. Might be time for a change and get off all those spam lists!

Cheers, Rob.

```
Could not deliver message to the following recipient(s):

Failed Recipient: tony.blair@unforgettable.com
Reason: Remote host said: 440 4.4.0  MSG=:  (DYN:T1)  
http://postmaster.info.aol.com/errors/421dynt1.html

    -- The header and top 20 lines of the message follows --

Received: from mx253o.mysite4now.com [216.10.248.253] by 
smtpgw02.myhostguy.com with SMTP;
    Wed, 23 Sep 2009 06:47:17 -0700
Received: from dedi561 (216-10-246-190.mysite4now.com 
[216.10.246.190]) by mx253o.mysite4now.com with SMTP;
    Wed, 23 Sep 2009 06:47:01 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "HOPS Help" <help@whatpub.org>
To: tony.blair@unforgettable.com
Date: 23 Sep 2009 06:47:00 -0700
Subject: WhatPub beer scores
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's saying the IP at unforgettable.com is being blocked.

Not sure what the problem is, but one thing to note is that if your email server doesn't adequately authenticate senders (SMTP use), then the server will be marked as an open relay and blocked (as it should be).

Comment: webhost4life's smtp servers do require authenticaton so they are okay on that score.

Answer (score 0):

WebHost4ForLife is an inferior hosting provider, that's the problem. I'm getting errors sending mail to AOL today too. Probably a whitelist/blacklist thing, but not the first problem I've had with email in the last few weeks that was their fault.

I'm changing from these clowns to someone more reliable ASAP.  I submitted a support ticket, let's see if they can fix it within 48 hours not like last time I suffered due to their inability to keep things up and running...

And this answer doesn't have the nasty "B" word in it, let's see if that's why my post was voted out or if perhaps there's people here who are personally offended by my dislike of webhost4life. =)

Comment: I would love to do the same for this web app but we're cost constrained with www.whatpub.org. I'm well aware of the bad press that WebHost4Life gets but to be honest, it's okay for us. Yes, their servers are overloaded and the worker process crashes/recycles frequently but we need lots of SQL space and nobody else compares on price. I've found support very helpful and respondeded quickly.

But it's useful to find that it's a black list issue.

Comment: UPDATE: I did another test this morning and that got through fine so, fingers crossed - it's fixed.

Comment: Hi Rob, I understand where you're coming from.  I too am constrained by costs, but am perhaps not as technically constrained as you are.  As my WH4L annual service comes to a close in a few months, I'll be checking out discountasp.net, my third try at affordable web hosting in the last couple of years.

FYI, I did receive a reply from WH4L's support people: 

###
Hi, I have changed some setting of your mail server, would you mind to try it again?

Thanks 

###

Seems to be OK now.  I just with they'd stop mucking with mail servers.  A few weeks ago I couldn't send email from ASP.NET code. =(

Comment: In WH4L's defence - the service has been very reliable and my only gripe is their web servers are overloaded and my webapp gets shut down too often making it feel even slower. No other host offers so much SQL space for the same price. However, CAMRA may finally get it's own hosting which will be *so* much better.